# Can't connect to Dreamhost's database

Tags: php, mysql, dreamhost

at first sorry for my english, i've a important question to resolve.
I'm trying to connect to my dreamhost's database but it's returninng the following error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've contacted Dreamhost support and they told me that 
it looks like the error was the result of using a newly created database
hostname.

I see that the hostname is now working properly

Now, I have a php class to connect to my database.
this is my command to connect:

```
$data = new MysqlClass('mysql.test.masterweblab.com','user','pass','data_name');
```

This works on my localhost. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: if *"This works on my localhost"* then what is your problem?

Comment: If you're getting an error message that says it's trying to connect to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, it doesn't look like your hostname in your class is being used.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com sorry i was not clear. With "this work on my localhost" i mean, when i use this code on my MAMP server it work, then my code is right ex.`code`$data = new MysqlClass('localhost','localuser','localpass','local_database');`code`

Comment: @whamma thank's for reply. Now i try with another code and re-post

Comment: Your problem is using Dreamhost in the first place.  Just look at how many outages they have:  https://twitter.com/dhstatus/  Used to work for a startup that used them and had 6 hours of downtime a week.  Those clowns have no idea how to operate a data center.

Comment: @Ramboz89 I don't know how your class tries to connect to MySQL but it should not be trying to use `mysql.sock` as you're not connecting to a `localhost` but rather a remote host so I would start by posting your relevant connection code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe they are using a different version of php or mysql than on your localhost?

try connecting to it like this on a new page and see if this works.

```
$link = mysql_connect("mysql.test.masterweblab.com", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("data_name") or die(mysql_error());

if ($link){
    echo "it worked!";
}else{
    echo "Failed " . mysql_error() ;
}

mysql_close();
```

If that doesn't work try pinging the host from a command prompt in windows.  Copy the ip address and try.

```
$link = mysql_connect("THE_IP_YOU_COPIED", "USER", "PASS");
mysql_select_db("data_name")or die(mysql_error());

if ($link){
    echo "it worked!"
}else{
    echo "Failed " . mysql_error() ;
}

mysql_close();
```

Let us know what that produces.

if you cant get the ip from pinging the domain there's your problem!  Log into cpanel and get your sql servers ip from phpmyadmin.